# Update a row in database appear an error in PHP

Tags: php, sql-update

hi buddy after asking 3 questions about the same idea I finally found it but there is an error I don't know from what is the error.
that's the code
the main page echo the data from the database to a table on the page.
Main page.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; 
$user="root";  
$pass=""; 
$datab_name="test"; 
$table_name="updat_tst"; 

mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$pass")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$datab_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $table_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td colspan="4"><strong>List data from mysql </strong> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Lastname</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Update</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['lastname']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['email']; ?></td>

<td align="center"><a href="updatedata.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">update</a></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
mysql_close();
?>
```

then on click update redirect to updatedata.php
and this is it's code
update.php shows a 3 textboxes that contains the data which you can edit it.

```
<?php
$host="localhost";  
$username="root"; 
$password=""; 
$db_name="test"; 
$tbl_name="test_mysql"; 

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="updateaction.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Update data in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Lastname</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Email</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $rows['name']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" value="<?php echo $rows['lastname']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<?php echo $rows['email']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

then the updateaction.php should update the data but it echo out ERROR

```
<?php
$host="localhost";  
$username="root"; 
$password=""; 
$db_name="test"; 
$tbl_name="test_mysql"; 

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="update_ac.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Update data in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Lastname</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Email</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $rows['name']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" value="<?php echo $rows['lastname']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<?php echo $rows['email']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

So do you see any mistake I did here in this code?

Comment: Sidenote 1 : Do not use `mysql_*` functions. Instead use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` as the former is deprecated and will not be supported in the future. http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should

Comment: Can you specify the error you are receiving?

Comment: Sidenote 2 : You don't need to close the mysql connection at the end manually. After reaching the end of the file, php automatically does it.

Comment: Please spcify the error message you are getting.We dont see any update query

Comment: Where is the code for `update_ac.php`? This where your form is getting submitted to.

Comment: Thanks everyone for trying to Help me 
I found the mistake that in update.php 
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"> should to be
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"> I missed <?php

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is OK but you just need to some changes in your updateaction.php Page.

```
$tbl_name = "test_mysql";
$sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='$name', lastname='$lastname', email='$email', WHERE id='$id'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0 )
{
    echo ("Data updated");
}
else 
{
    echo ("Data not updated!!");
}
    //echo ($query);
}
$qry = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_nam WHERE id='$id'";
$rs = mysql_query($qry);
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
```

Comment: Thanks for your Help
I found the mistake that in update.php 
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"> should to be
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"> I missed <?php